# Trying to make an internal redirect from "example.com/about" to "example.com?p=about"

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, internal, internal-server-error

I am trying to make an internal redirect (without changing the url in the client-browser) from "example.com/about" to "example.com?p=about".

I added the the folowing code to my .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !\?
RewriteRule ([^\/]*)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}?p=$1 [L]
```

But if I open the page (example.com/about), I am getting an **internal server error**

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Thanks for helping

**Edit:** If I add the R flag to the RewriteRule, everything works fine

Answer (score 0):

You got error because your rule just add query string then capture again any URI even passed through this rule before so,Your rules should look like this :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}?p=$1 [L]
```

And to be more specific and able to handle real wrong requests by any other rule  , do this :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !p=(.*)
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}?p=$1 [L]
```